# Need help to split a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would need to split a string such as :

```
1 kg sugar, 100 pound flour, 10 g salt, 1 1/4 cup of flour, 1,5 piece of stuff or 1.5 cup of water
```

And that should return something like:

```
["1 kg sugar", "100 pound flour", "10 g salt", "1 1/4 cup of flour", "1,5 piece of stuff", "1.5 cup of water"]
```

the pattern can be kind of funky. But let's say it always start by a number and must finish by a letter

Comment: so basically you want to split a string by commas and the word `or`? what have you tried? (also I think splitting on or is probably a bad idea)

Comment: You can say it, but it doesn't match your example.

Comment: Remove `[` and `]`, then Split with `,`. Not sure about that `""`.

Comment: `,` split will not work since `1,5` has also a coma

Comment: `always start by a number and must finish by a letter` So the substring `1 k` is valid ?

Comment: there are both , and . separators for floating numbers, is it on purpose?

Comment: @Mark You're right. I overlooked it. Regex may help..

Comment: The string must start by a number, and should stop when hitting anything else that is not a letter. So in my exemple the 'or' should be part of the array I guess

Comment: @Mark - I think the `1,5` is an error in this question since it also includes `1.5`. If not then the op can just look for entries in the split where it contains a single number and append this entry to the next one

Comment: @WaZz What about `1,5 piece of stuff` ?

Comment: 1.5 or 1,5 are valid values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution. Not sure if it is the best way, but I am using regex to extract what need

```
string pattern = @"[0-9][0-9 /.,]+[a-zA-Z ]+";
string input = line;

var result = new List<string>();

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
   result.Add(m.Value.Trim());

return result;
```

This piece of code returns what I need such as

```
new[] { "1 kg sugar", "100 pound flour", "10 g salt", "1 1/4 cup of flour", "1.5  piece of stuff or", "1.5 cup of water" }
```

From there, I'll loop to remove all undesired words such as 'or' and Trim() again.

Answer (score 0):

replace all

```
(, )|( or )
```

by

```
", "
```

Add a `["` at the beginning and `"]` at the end of the result.

Don't know anything about a c#, just used the RegexCoach to test it.

Comment: Seems like there is a @Conffusion here...

Comment: I assumed c# has regular expression possibilities in it.

Comment: But output should be an array not a new string. (This is what I understand from *Split* :) )

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need a regex. Split the string on comma and space.

```
var input = "1 kg sugar, 100 pound flour, 10 g salt, 1 1/4 cup of flour, 1,5 piece of stuff or 1.5 cup of water";
var results = input.Split(new [] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DSbokx)

Result:

```
1 kg sugar 
100 pound flour 
10 g salt 
1 1/4 cup of flour 
1,5 piece of stuff or 1.5 cup of water
```

Comment: what about "1,5 piece"

Comment: Works fine since it is split on comma and space together as the delimiter.

Comment: There is not such overload of Split `.Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: I already noticed that. Thanks I4V.